# Can SQLite support multiple users?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to develop a Windows based application with multiple users accessing the same database at the same time. Can SQLite support multiple accesses at one time? Is SQLite stable in this regard? What makes SQLite better or worse than MS SQL CE?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you care sharing with us what did you end-up doing? Thanks.

Comment: By design, "SQLite Is Embedded, Not Client-Server" - see: https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html. In addition "SQLite supports an unlimited number of simultaneous readers, but it will only allow one writer at any instant in time. For many situations, this is not a problem. Writers queue up. Each application does its database work quickly and moves on, and no lock lasts for more than a few dozen milliseconds. But there are some applications that require more concurrency, and those applications may need to seek a different solution." Ref: https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Comment: [Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same application access a single database file at the same time?](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) & [SQLite Concurrency](https://charlesleifer.com/blog/sqlite-small-fast-reliable-choose-any-three-/)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Yes SQLite can support multiple users at once. It does however lock the whole database when writing, so if you have lots of concurrent writes it is not the database you want (usually the time the database is locked is a few milliseconds - so for most uses this does not matter). But it is very well tested and very stable (and widely used) so you can trust it.

You may read this short document for information when to use SQLite and not: http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Comment: I found it to be MUCH quicker than MSSQL CE.

Comment: Just a bump. So if we have 10 insert commands executed once every 100 ms and the writing for each takes less than 10 ms we should have no problem? So I guess the server (apache) somehow takes care of the writing queue then.

Comment: There is also the [WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) for increasing concurrency, allowing reads to still occur during a write. (But not allowing concurrent writes although ambiguous at first about this: there is a sentence in Concurrency § stating this.)

Comment: There may be an issue with multiple users (as in linux user accounts). It may not work in WAL mode or when using shared memory. I have observed that the .db-shm and .db-wal files were created with the other user as the owner and group. This prevented the application (running as the user that owns the .db file) from doing transactions.

Comment: @K.KilianLindberg if you have 1000 inserts a second from multiple users, you genuinely need something more grunty than sqlite3.  sqlite is remarkably performant, but its absolutely not tuned for performance in a multiuser context. For something like that I strongly advocate Postgres or something of that calibre.

Answer (score 19):

Yes.
From [paragraph #5](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5) in [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html):

> Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time. Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But **only one process can be making changes to the database at any moment** in time, however.

Comment: Users are not processes

Answer (score 18):

If concurrent writes are an issue, you may want to look at [Berkeley DB](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/related/berkeleydb.html). The SQL API is completely SQLite compatible. In fact, it incorporates the SQLite executor top of Berkeley DB's storage engine, which **does** support multiple concurrent write operations.