# sqlite, triggers and concurrency

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am developing an application that uses an SQLite trigger that is in the form

```
CREATE TRIGGER bar_to_foo AFTER INSERT ON bar
  BEGIN
    DELETE * FROM foo;
    INSERT INTO foo SELECT FROM bar;
  END;
```

Multiple users will be using the application at the same time and potentially inserting into bar at the same time.

My question is: is there a chance that the triggers will execute in parallel?  If so, the two deletes may happen before the inserts, which would result in a foo that contains bar twice over.  This is not what I want - ideally, I'd the entirety of the trigger to execute before it reruns.  If this is not default behavior in sqlite, is there a way to specify that this should happen?

Comment: What on earth is the business requirement for this? Also, depending on the number of concurrent users, you might encounter severe performance problems, since SQLite is not designed for multi-user usage, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102027/can-sqlite-support-multiple-user

Comment: It's not for business - it's for custom file format reading and writing.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite properly serializes all transactions.
(And when you are not using explicit transaction, each top-level statement will be wrapped in an automatic transaction.)

No two transactions can write to the same database at the same time, whether from inside a trigger or in any other way.