# Multiple python connections to same sqlite Database table

Tags: python, database, sqlite, multiple-instances

I am trying write two processes using python that require access to same sqlite database table. One of the process updates the table by inserting new data and the other process retrieves information from the same table. However when the other second process runs select query the data base is already locked and I get 
the **"OperationalError: database is locked"**. Following are the code for both processes. Appreciate any help

```
    process : 1
    ------------
    while True:

        print "Updating"
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL')
            c.executemany('INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', insertdata)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        except:
            pass           
        time.sleep(60)

    process : 2
    ------------

        conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("select * from test_table where id='{}' and date = '{}' order by time desc".format(recv_data,datetime.datetime.now().date().isoformat()))
        data= c.fetchall()  
        conn.close()
```

The link given above only suggests that multiple connection in sqlite is possible. However it doesn't suggest how to do it

Comment: more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102027/can-sqlite-support-multiple-user

Comment: The link given above only suggests that multiple connection in sqlite is possible. However it doesn't suggest how to do it

Comment: I tried your code: writing every 5 seconds, reading every 0.1 seconds (python 3.4.2, sqlite 3.8.10.2) and could not reproduce your error message - perhaps you have an out of date version.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I re-installed the packages and the code worked

Answer (score 0):

The database blocks the access after any writing operation during some milliseconds hence you can try a `time.sleep(1)` in the process: 2 to avoid this collision at least the first time.

Comment: ,@Richard, I think that is not the issue. As the default timeout setting for sqlite is 5 seconds, lock of few milliseconds shouldn't cause the problem. I think the problem is something else.