# is sql is suitable for this kind of my small database base project in c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

hy am developing a database system Program for a local shop, where i have 5 computers, 1 will act as server and remaining 4 as client, these 4 client computers are just connected with server computer to get Data while just  server's program is also connected with Sql Database, and this Database have 10 tables and 1500 users record(name,address,email,number,salary,daily attendance).
so my questions are

1. IS Sql dataBase is suitable for this project ? as i want to use Database
2. If Sql is Better than how much Sql Db Can store Data in it ? This DB program will be in use for 5 years more
3. How I can Take Back Up of this Database ?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. A few Gigabytes at least depending on the version (loads more than a local shop will need). 3. Using SSIS or the backup options in SQL server management studio :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IS Sql dataBase is suitable for this project ? as i want to use Database

Yes

> If Sql is Better than how much Sql Db Can store Data in it ? This DB program will be in use for 5 years more

Depends on the version of SQL Server you use and the volume of data you will be generating. Without further info it's hard to answer, but I'm guessing you will be ok.

> How I can Take Back Up of this Database ?

Again, depends on the version you are going to use. SQL Server has a built-in backup system for all the different types and I don't think it changes in the way it works between server types, unless you are getting in to using replication.

To be honest, SQL Server it probably overkill for this application. Take a look at SQLite or even the Jet databases (as used by MS-Access)

Comment: i want to store daily attendance, monthly salary of employee including their personal information name email contact number age gender this program ill be used for next 5 years, so how much volume ?

Comment: That sounds like a small amount of data, I don't think there will be any problems whatever database system you use. If you really want to calculate it, work out the size in bytes of the rows you will store, estimate the number of rows added daily then multiply that up for 5 years.

Comment: means your suggestion is to use SQLite with c# for this project ?

Comment: I'm only suggesting you compare some other database systems, given the size of you project. To answer with a question, what got you thinking of using SQL Server in the first place? Did someone suggest it or is that the only database you know about?

Comment: One of the reasons I suggested something like SQLite or Jet is they are single files. The backup part of your question then becomes a simple file copy which can be performed using freely available backup software - or build it in to your application to make a copy at night when the database is not in use.

Comment: no one suggested me Sql, i just knew this and it was easy to use in c# as local Database ,

Comment: In which case that makes it very suitable, It's always good to work with technologies you know. There are going to be enough other problems to resolve when writing the app, there's no need to add the pain of learning a new database and api :)

Comment: Sqlite and sql server have same features ? means sqlite perform all which sql perform ?

Comment: They both store and retrieve data... what specific features of SQL Server would you be worried about losing if you used a different database?

Comment: no specific features i need, i just want Data should not be lost, easy to connect via c# and can use able for 5 years for small Data, sqlite can do this na ?

Comment: Yes, it can do that. There's a load of information available on the web, even a MSDN article about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases

Comment: You might find this SO question useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102027/can-sqlite-support-multiple-user