# manage, query, and split,combine, apply many local csv datafiles? probably using database?

Tags: python, mysql, matlab, sqlite, csv

I have a gigantic collection of csv files that acquired over a lengthy period of time and I continue to append with new acquisitions. The data files were arranged using the following logic.

each batch of files (~100 separate files) over one single trial study were saved in one folder (there are at least 30 different trials).
each file has a file name that identified location of data collection and sample name (different types), and probably manufactuer/date information as well. 
In each file, we have many columns (~200) of data containing many properties about the sample. Some of the columns provide qualitative/quantitative information such as component name and component level (%).

Now, suppose I want to find the set of data that contain certain components, from a few selected manufactuers in a few chosen studies. It would be really time consuming to extract those data by going over all folders and find those csv files and extract those data that satisfy the query conditions and then put them into a new file.

My question is:

1. Does there exist a solution to be able to extract those files by running an integrated query command to simply split/combine and apply operations without having to dig into individual files.
2. We are thinking of building a database management system. I think sqlite3 might be the way to go because it is serverless DB. Would it or any other DB platforms such as MySQL enable us to address our problem? I am using MatLAB and python as my data/file handling platform.
3. Is there any commercial/opensource software that provide such service, which I am not aware of?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to do analytics & data science on top of this data, for which you will query or create features for modeling, then:

1) You could write some query logic in python that only gets some files when needed and loads them to pandas or converts into bulk csv files, but would not be long-term sustainable.

2) DB is very likely the way to go. You could have a different table or database for each trial or each trial schema/structure.

3) SQLite3 is a good option, but a community version of MySQL might have greater flexibility. i.e. limitations of SQLite: [Can SQLite support multiple users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102027/can-sqlite-support-multiple-users) Of course, for development, you could do that in SQLite to start, and to load everything from text files, and migrate to something like MySQL later.

If you model the process well from the beginning (python -> ETL -> DB -> features for modeling), and have good structure for your SQL environment, it should last a very long time in either a lab or workplace.