# Alternate solution for portable database other than sqlite for python program

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, sqlite, portability

I'm comfortable with sqlite but when I use two different python program to access the same database. It throws an error like table is locked.

What are the different portable database to use with python?

Comment: You could load the DB file into a SQLite in-memory DB, make any queries/updates and write it back to disk. In-memory SQLite DBs allow for connections from multiple threads/processes.

Comment: "Database is locked" shows that you forgot to set the [busy timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout) to 30 s or so. "Table is locked" shows that your program is buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is great but is designed as a small, fast, single user database. it isn't designed for the use you describe.

You can just pretty much any database with Python. The [Python database API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) provides a straightforward way to interface with most relational databases, including SQLite.

However, to interact with a database in a more natural Python style, I've enjoyed using [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html). It took a bit to work through the tutorial but it's great.

My personal preferred database is Postgres, but there are many other choices.

Comment: I'm looking for a portable database where I can move the complete code and db directory to another machine and running them again without any problem

Comment: That isn't what "portable" conventionally means. In this case, when you use "portable" you mean "can copy the database files to another machine as part of the source tree and the app will run". If you _really_ want to use SQLite, [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102027/can-sqlite-support-multiple-users). Alternatively, write the data to files using some persistence library (e.g. pickle, protobufs, flatbuffer, etc). Or just use a database ;)