# How many users can Sqlite can handle , Django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have a Django application, which I hosted on pythonanywhere. For the database, I have used SQLite(default).
So I want to know how many users my applications can handle?
And what if two user register form or make post at same time, will my application will crash?

Comment: I'm not sure if Django would add any constraints, but this one is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102027/can-sqlite-support-multiple-users/5102145

Comment: If you are creating a multi-user web site I do not recommend using SQLite ... use MySQL or some other "real" SQL server.  The only place where I use SQLite is for a few sites that consist only of static pages:  in that scenario, SQLite conveniently stores all the page images in one file, but the database contents are never "updated" except by me ... off-line.  The scenario you describe contra-indicates the use of SQLite.

Comment: PythonAnywhere developer here: @MikeRobinson is entirely correct.  SQLite is a great database to use when you're getting started, and in general it will not break things with multiple users -- that is, it will not corrupt your data -- but it will be really slow, especially with more than a few users.  I'd definitely recommend MySQL as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite supports multiple users, however it locks the database when write operations is being executed.

In other words,concurrent writes cannot be treated with this database, so is not recommended.

You can use PostgreSQL or MySQL as an alternative.