# Can multiple users write to an SQLite database, or is it purely local

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I was wondering, does sqlite allow multiple users to write and read the same database, or is sqlite stored locally, therefore not allowing multiple users to use the same database.

Comment: SQLite is designed for beings accessed by a single process. If you want to serve multiple clients consider using a database server like MariaDB, Postgres and many others.

Comment: Please see [Can SQLite support multiple users?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5102027/1422451). SQLite allows unlimited reading but will lock database on writing but that only happens at milliseconds. If multiple users are not millions running many concurrent transactions, SQLite is a suitable backend solution.