# Multithreaded reads and writes to a single SQlite database using the C API

Tags: c, sqlite

My application consists of a number of threads (typically 5-10) and each is responsible for reading a value from an SQLite database, working on it for an amount of time and then writing a new value back to the database.

Each of the threads is running by itself without any synchronization.

My question is: Do I need to write the synchronization code myself or it is possible to interact with the SQLite C API in such a way that this gets taken care of for you.  IE. If there is a transaction in progress to write a value and a different thread tries to write or read the same row, SQLite will block until it's okay to do so?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5102027/1606345

Comment: Did you read https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html ? (I suggest multi-threaded with one connection per thread)

Comment: @DavidRanieri - thank you and similar I think. I may well have lots of concurrent writes so this may not be the right solution for me.

Comment: @Shawn I did but there isn't much detail there AFAICT.  I think the mode I want is SERIALIZED and all the docs say is "Serialized. In serialized mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads with no restriction." - that doesn't seem to be the same as what JohnBollinger said in his answer below.

Comment: Serialized is good for read-only or the rare cases of wanting transactions to cover to all threads at once. For the case you described in your question it's not suitable.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to write the synchronization code myself or it is possible to interact with the SQLite C API in such a way that this gets taken care of for you.

The [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) covers this.  In a nutshell, SQLite has three different threading models available:

- *single-thread*, in which all internal mutexes are disabled, and the SQLite API cannot safely be used by multiple threads at the same time;
- *multi-thread*, in which the library can safely be used concurrently by multiple threads, but database connections can be used only by a single thread at a time; and
- *serialized*, in which multiple threads can use the API concurrently without restriction.

There is a built-in default selected at compile time (which is "serialized" mode in a standard build).  A different mode can be selected during library initialization (`sqlite3_config()`), and a per-connection thread mode can be specified when you open a new connection, ***except that*** single-thread mode cannot be overridden.

But note well that under all circumstances, SQLite provides a single transaction at a time per connection.  Thus, you may need your own synchronization even in "serialized" mode.

> If there is a transaction in progress to write a value and a different thread tries to write or read the same row, SQLite will block until it's okay to do so?

If an SQLite connection is in serialized mode and has autocommit enabled, then you're fine, in the sense that each statement will be executed in its own transaction, and different threads will not interfere with each other (but they may *counteract* each other).  If a connection is instead in the weaker "multi-thread" mode then you must provide your own synchronization, so that different threads do not attempt to use the connection concurrently.  If autocommit is disabled, then you will probably need to synchronize even in "serialized" mode to accommodate multiple threads using the same connection, else you will be unable to effectively control transaction boundaries and the contents of each transaction.

With respect to a single, established connection, there is no meaningful difference between "multi-thread" mode and "single-thread" mode.

Comment: Thank you very much John - I am new to this so trying to digest your informative post.  I think if I go with the default serialized mode, I can be sure each statement will be completed successfully but it's not certain that there may be unintended side effects such as operations out of order?  If so, do I need to bracket each statement I write with `BEGIN_TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` ?

Comment: @MollyBirk, if your connection is operating in autocommit mode then you do not need explicit `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` statements (in fact, I think SQLite will reject them in that case).  And if autocommit mode is sufficient for your needs then it is your easiest way forward.  That does not impose relative ordering of different threads' database interactions, but it's not clear to me whether you need that.

Answer (score 1):

> If there is a transaction in progress to write a value and a different thread tries to write or read the same row, SQLite will block until it's okay to do so?

The easy way to do this is use mult-threaded mode, with one connection object per thread. Then threads can acquire a lock on the database with a `BEGIN IMMEDIATE` transaction, and if you get a `SQLITE_BUSY` error, the thread can either do something else for a while before trying again, or if you had set up a [busy timeout](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/busy_timeout.html) ahead of time to a reasonable for your needs timeout, the thread will just sleep for up to that length of time trying to acquire the transaction lock periodically before giving up.

If you use serialized mode and a single connection for the entire program, you have to include all the logic and locking to make sure that only one particular thread can access the database when a transaction is active yourself. Much easier to use sqlite's native, well tested, support for that functionality.