# Problem with SQLite database locking when multiple users try to save data simultaneously in Lazarus

Tags: sqlite, delphi, pascal, lazarus

I have a problem with saving data to a SQLite database in Lazarus. When several users try to save data to the database at the same time, a collision occurs because the database is locked.

Has anyone had a similar problem and knows how to solve it? Maybe there is a mechanism that allows waiting for access to the database?

Below is sample code that initiates the problem:

```
SQLite3Connection1.Connected:=true;

sql:= 'Insert into data (a, b, c) values (:a, :b, :c)';

SQLMaterial.SQL.Text:=sql;
SQLMaterial.ParamByName('a').AsString:=text1;
SQLMaterial.ParamByName('b').AsString:=text2;
SQLMaterial.ParamByName('c').AsString:=text3;

SQLMaterial.ExecSQL;  <-- collision problem

SQLMaterial.Close;
SQLite3Connection1.Connected:=false;
```

Thanks

I'm still learning and haven't found a suitable solution yet.

Comment: Duplicate maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102027/can-sqlite-support-multiple-users

Comment: You need to use another database system which supports multiple users simultaneously, SQLite doesn't support this!

Comment: Have you tried setting [busy_timeout](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout)?

Answer (score 1):

PRAGMA busy_timeout - proved to be a good solution.

```
 SQLite3Connection1.ExecuteDirect('PRAGMA busy_timeout = 3000;');
 SQLite3Connection1.Connected:=true;

 sql:= 'Insert into data (a, b, c) values (:a, :b, :c)';

 SQLMaterial.SQL.Text:=sql;
 SQLMaterial.ParamByName('a').AsString:=text1;
 SQLMaterial.ParamByName('b').AsString:=text2;
 SQLMaterial.ParamByName('c').AsString:=text3;

 SQLMaterial.ExecSQL; 

 SQLMaterial.Close;
 SQLite3Connection1.Connected:=false;
```

Comment: Was the code in your example supposed to be surrounded by backticks?  Just checking to make sure that wasn't a typo.